# Change mouseover thumb effect from zoom out to zoom in

Tags: html, css

I found a mouseover effect online not too long ago, but I want to change it a bit. Currently it zooms out on mouseover, but I want it to zoom IN instead. So the default state is the actual dimensions of the thumbs, and then mouseover zooms in on them the way they currently zoom out.

**Here's the CSS/HTML code on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9TbE/5/**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="thumbs"> <a href="project.html">
        <span class="thumbInfo">Client Name<h4>Project Name</h4></span>
        <img class="lazy" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQPEOsFC2tci90_yQTxEfD5gXWOBzI3Rz2wIchkmm2VdNBN57RttD4kiUk" alt="" />
    </a>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thumbs {
    width: 219px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.no-margin {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.thumbs a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbs a img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    top: -10px;
    left: -20px;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbs a span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:'EurostileLT-Demi', Verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    padding-top: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
}
.thumbs a span h4 {
    font-family:'EurostileLT', Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbs').mouseenter(function (e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({
            height: '170',
            left: '0',
            top: '0',
            width: '219'
        }, 100);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function (e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({
            height: '200',
            left: '-20',
            top: '-10',
            width: '250'
        }, 100);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Can anyone please help me out? :-)
I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: you can do it with only css also. what you have to do is on hover just scale the image. you can use this http://ferretarmy.com/files/css-animation/tutorial1/examples/example1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.thumbs a img {
    width: 219px;
    height: 170px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbs').mouseenter(function (e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({
            height: '200', // Changed this part
            left: '-20',   // *
            top: '-10',    // *
            width: '250'   // *
        }, 100);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function (e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({
            height: '170', // With this part
            left: '0',     // *
            top: '0',      // *
            width: '219'   // *
        }, 100);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

What I did is: I changed the default `CSS` settings for the `<img>` to be zoomed out at the beginning and changed the `Javascript` so it is zooming in instead of zooming out on `mouseenter` and zooming out instead of in on `mouseleave`.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9TbE/6/

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much codezombie. Works like a charm :)